# Creating A Timeline In JSON File and Updating Page According To Datetime In That JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json, events

I'm not sure I can fully explain myself but I have a project and this project serves a JSON that includes missions. This JSON file can be updated continuously. structure could be like below:

```
[
   {
    "module_id": 5,
    "title": "TITLE 1",
    "media_path": "/img/src/aa.jpg",
    "start_time": "2019-08-13 21:50:00",
    "finish_time": "2019-08-30 23:59:00"
   },
   {
    "module_id": 10,
    "title": "TITLE 2",
    "media_path": "/video/src/aa.mp4",
    "start_time": "2019-08-30 23:59:00",
    "finish_time": "2019-09-30 23:59:00"
   },
   {
    "module_id": 15,
    "title": "TITLE 3",
    "media_path": "/img/src/cc.jpg",
    "start_time": "2019-09-30 23:59:00",
    "finish_time": "2019-10-30 23:59:00"
   }
]
```

My question is:

Can I update page without refreshing according to the `datetime` in JSON file. When the next `start_time` approaches, I wanna load the media in the background and when the `start_time` comes I wanna change the design of page according to `module_id`. Every module_id will have own page design.

So the page design and content will change without refreshing page according to `module_id`'s own design when time comes.

Hope I could explain myself. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Assuming the JSON file is called "missions.json"

```
class MissionsChecker ()
{
    constructor () {
        this.loadMissionsFile("missions.json");
        this.running = false;
    }

    start () {
        if (!this.running) {
            this.checkMissions();
            this.running = true;
        }
    }

    stop () {
        if (this.running) {
            clearInterval(this.missionChecker);
            this.running = false;
        }
    }

    loadMissionsFile (filename) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", filename, false);

        var self = this;
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.status == 200 && this.readyState == 4) {

                self.missions = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            }
        }

        req.send(null);
    }

    getFullDate () {
        var date = new Date();

        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth();
        var day = date.getDate();

        if (month.length < 2) {
            month = "0" + String(month);
        }

        return String(year) + "-" + String(month) + "-" + String(day);
    }

    getFullTime () {
        var date = new Date();

        var hour = date.getFullYear();
        var minutes = date.getMonth();
        var seconds = date.getDate();

        if (hour.length < 2) {
            hour = "0" + String(hour);
        }

        if (minutes.length < 2) {
            minutes = "0" + String(minutes);
        }

        if (seconds.length < 2) {
            seconds = "0" + String(seconds)
        }

        return String(hour) + ":" + String(minutes) + ":" + String(seconds);
    }

    select (selector) {
        return document.querySelector(selector);
    }

    checkMissions () {
        var self = this;

        this.missionChecker = setInterval(function () {
            for (var missionGroup of self.missions) {
                var currentDateTime = self.getFullDate() + " " + self.getFullTime();

                if (missionGroup.start_time == currentDateTime) { // You'd probably need to modify this
                    document.title = missionGroup.title;

                    var imgElem = this.select(".img-holder"); // where ".img-holder" is the element that is to have its background image changed
                    imgElem.style.imageBackground = missionGroup.media_path;

                    if (missionGroup.module_id == match) { // where "match" is the module_id to be matched
                        // your UI-changing JavaScript code will go in here
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Oh and to check for missions run `new MissionsChecker().start()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Same question for you too: Any error happens in the long run like 20-24 hours if I use setInterval 1 second. The tab will stay open for a long time as I said.

Comment: The tab will stay open as long as the user wants. `setInterval(...)` will make sure that the callback function gets executed repeatedly (until the user closes the tab or there's an error in the loop)

Comment: What if my JSON file has 50,000 objects. Is it okay to loop every second

Comment: heck no. In that case you'd have to remove the "seconds" indicator in the start_time and loop every 30-45 seconds

Comment: I'm working on an interactive social TV app. So admin can save an event that will loop every minute, hour, 6 hours etc. Many events can be displayed on TV  in different time. So how can I implement this? How is the solution that using MySQL event scheduler and run query to insert into a table and read that table by EventSource of JS.

Comment: You can use the class above. You'll need to make some adjustments in order to accommodate the loop interval. Basically you'll need to add two parameters to the constructor - one for the loop interval and another for the callback. When the interval time is up the callback will be initialized, thereby sending the missionGroup (or tvEvent - as the case may be) to the callback function

Answer (score 1):

You could use `setTimeout` then each interval checks the current time `new Date()` against all JSON file times. Something a little like this;

```
jsonFiles.forEach(file => {
  const fileStart = new Date(file.start_time);
  const fileEnd = new Date(file.end_time);

  const now = new Date();

  if(fileStart <= now && fileEnd >= now){
    // chnage ui here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But tab will stay open for a long time like 20-24 hours. Is it okay to use setTimeout or setInterval for this. Any error happens in the long run?

Comment: It will be fine. the 'timer'  of ```setTimeout``` runs outside the main thread of execution so it will have no performance implications on the rest of your code & site.